# Minimum Extjs version for Sencha Cmd and it's differences with Extjs 4.1.1

Tags: extjs, cmd, extjs4

Is ExtJs 4.1.1 different from ExtJs 4.1.1a ?

https://github.com/probonogeek/extjs/commits/master

[image]

I am working in a project that uses 4.1.1 but when trying to use the Sencha Cmd (4.05) looks like the cmd folder is missing so now I realise that the minimum supported version is 4.1.1a [image: cmd compatibility matrix]

**Can I simply replace 4.1.1 with 4.1.1a?**

Comment: You can simple replace the whole ext folder... or create a project in 4.1.1a using cmd and then place in your files. You may find some functions breaking (not sure what changed from 1 to 1a)

Comment: This link for more info - http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?243153-Sencha-Cmd-V3-Beta